# Which loss function to use when there are many outputs?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, loss-function

Data similar to the images of 1000 x 1 pixels come from the equipment. Somewhere in the image may be 1, 2 or more objects.

I'm going to build a neural network to detect objects. I want to make 1,000 outputs. Each output will indicate whether there is an object in that output or not. 
Advise me which loss function to use.

It seems to me that "categorical crossentropy" is not suitable, because for example: in the training data, I will indicate that the objects are at 10 and 90 pixels. And the neural network will predict that the objects are at 11 and 89 pixels. It's not a big loss. But for the network, it will be the same loss as if it predict objects at 500 and 900 pixels.

What loss function is suitable for such a case ?
I'm using Keras

Comment: Finding the location of an object in an image is a regression problem. For a regression problem, you could use a MSE as the cost function.

Comment: Does MSE take into account that the mistake of choosing output11 instead of output10 is less than the mistake of choosing output500 instead of output10?

Comment: Have you read any papers about using Neural Networks to do Object Detection? Because they contain all the answers you need. For example the SSD or YOLO papers

Comment: I find it difficult to read papers because it have a lot of mathematics, studying it takes a lot of time. But the papers you cited are quite clear. Please advise some more papers.

Answer (score 1):

In object detection mainly we have two tasks- localization and classification. Therefore, we have two loss for two tasks- one is localization and another is classification loss. It is calculated using IoU(intersection over Union).
more details [here.](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2018/12/27/object-detection-part-4.html#loss-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can use binary cross entropy loss and set the nearest n-bins to the ground truth as labels.

For example, you have 10 pixels and ground truth label is 3 and you selected 3 neighbours.

In typical categorical cross entropy, you would set label as follow using one-hot encoded vector.

[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

In the solution I suggested, you would use this

[0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]

Or it can be this, basically imposing a Gaussian instead of flat labels.

[0 0.5 1 0.5 0 0 0 0 0 0]

---

Object detection architectures as suggested in the comments also essentially behave the same way I described. Except that they use a quantized scheme

[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] (actual pixels)

[- - 1 - - - - 0 - -] (group into 2 groups of 5. Your network only has two outputs now. Think of this as binning stage, as the actual pixel belong to group 1. this subnetwork uses binary cross entropy).

[1 0] (first classification network output)

[-1 0] (this second stage can be thought of as delta network, it takes the classified bin value from first stage and outputs a correction value, as the first bin is anchored at index 2, you need to predict -1 to move it to index 1. this network is trained using smoothed l1 loss).

Now there is immediately a problem, what if there are two objects in  group 1? This is an unfortunate problem which also exists in object detection architecture. The way to workaround with this is to define slightly shifted and scaled bin(or anchor) positions. This way you can detect at one pixel maximum of N objects where N is the number of anchors defined at that pixel.

Comment: I understand the first part of your reply. I have already tried this part in my other project, and it works. But i think it's not quite the right way. I do not understand the second part of your reply. Do you suggest to separate input image into several groups and to predict objects in each group?  and then detect more accurate in each group with objects?

Comment: Yes you are essentially correct. This is how all current detection architectures works. Don't let the jargon confuse you. You don't have to follow exactly the way they do it. As long as you implement it by classifying first and refining the classification, you will achieve the same effect. Why is this a superior method? The thing is regression is a slow procedure. CNNs are not very good at it especially if the range to predict is large, but they are much better at classification, which requires you to quantize the output space. So you get the best of both worlds by combining them both.

Comment: You can get some idea on the details by reading either the faster-rcnn/yolo papers or if you are interested in an slightly different(but essentially the same thing) you can look at how people predict rotation using the similar approach(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.03225).  I also have a similar paper currently under review (https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.09899) using the same technique. What can you get with this approach?Based on my experience, you can train faster and get more accurate results than the first approach.However, if this two are not what you want, you can just stick with first method.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Siddharth, you'll use two loss functions, since you have a regression problem and a classification problem. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSwYGkTfOKk for more details. Particularly, pay attention to this slide:

[image]

That is, the first task simply classifies if the object is present (logistic regression loss) and the second task finds the bounding boxes (square error loss).